# pytest test class generator: order of tests

Tags: python, metaprogramming, pytest

I've created a test class generator:

```py
import pytest

def t_1(self):
    print("1")
    assert True
def t_2(self):
    print("2")
    assert True
def t_3(self):
    print("3")
    assert True


new_cls = type("TestClass", (), 
        {   
            "test_1": t_1,
            "test_0": t_2,
            "test_2": t_3 
        })  
TestClass = new_cls
```

The output (`python3 -m pytest -s test.py`) is:

```
1
2
3
```

My question: in these scenarios, how is the ordering of the tests determined? For example, if my functions I'm using are defined in other modules (or in functions), how do I know in what order these tests will execute?

Comment: Which version of python are you using? Looks like you're using one which has ordered dictionaries. Thus, the order is defined by the order in which the tests are added to the dictionary (the order in which they appear in the dictionary creation expression).

Answer (score 2):

First, your packages are sorted in alphabetical order, then test modules, test classes and finally test functions.

I'd recommend avoiding using dependent tests as it may cause certain issues.

If you want to apply your own ordering, try "pytest_collection_modifyitems" hook or some plugins like "pytest-ordering".